# pipe.all not working for special character such as "(" in filter

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to query a MongoDB Database in Golang using `c.Pipe`, but the response is always empty although I have items such as `("name": "test case ( parenthesis )")` in the database.

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"name":"("}}})

resp := []bson.M{}

err := pipe.All(&resp)

if err != nil {
  //handle error
}

fmt.Println(resp) // Empty resp
```

Comment: pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{map[$match:map[name:map[$options:i $regex:(]]]}})

a small change, i am using regex to filter

Comment: map[$match:map[name:map[$options:i $regex:.*\\(.*]]]

used this regex and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need a [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to query for a name **containing** character `(`. The regex should be `.*\(.*`.

Comment: pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{map[$match:map[name:map[$options:i $regex:(]]]}}) a small change, i am using regex to filter

Comment: tried with map[$match:map[name:map[$options:i $regex:.*(.*]]],...still same result

Comment: map[$match:map[name:map[$options:i $regex:.*\\(.*]]] used this regex and it worked :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape the character.